# couldn't validate the identity of the API Server

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, ip-address

```
root@server0:/home/ubuntu# kubeadm join XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:6443 --token rux9q7.7dqbdf4o8ezifo5p         --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:835dbbca81b20df1314a46f76f9f6c30d395fd9fb0a39a130d96c5f3ebeba7ff
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.0.0.71, not XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

how to fix? XXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX is this actually an external IP address.

Comment: what does ```external IP address``` mean , ideally it should be the IP address of the master node

Answer (score 0):

This was a name resolution problem for me. I added all my nodes (as FQDNs) and masters to the hosts file on the system experiencing this and it resolved it immediately. This could also be done in DNS if the hosts use a specific lookup domain.